Travel with passport expiring in a month
I am planning a trip to South Korea the first two weeks of June and I have a little concern. My Italian passport will expire in August (1.5 month after).
Normally when finalizing the trip I am normally asked for a "valid passport" so I think I will be fine.
But just to double-check is it fine to travel when the passport expiration date is due to?

TIMATIC (a travel document database) states

Passports and other documents accepted for entry must be valid on arrival.

TravelDoc (another competing database) does indicate the same as TIMATIC

Also this: https://ambseoul.esteri.it/it/servizi-consolari-e-visti/servizi-per-il-cittadino-italiano/informazioni-utili-allarrivo-in-corea/

Just to clarify (although is quite clear). As long as the documents are valid I should be good to go, right?

Should the following cause a problem then? https://m.flyasiana.com/C/VN/EN/contents/check-in-procedure-international-flights

@user8469759 No, this article mentions other countries, it's for exit not entry

My apologies. "No" to what? The "good to go" or "should the following cause a problem"?

@user8469759 The Asiana article, it's about departures to other countries

For Italian passport holders visiting South Korea, it is necessary for the passport to be valid for six months beyond the intended stay period as indicated here https://embassies.net/south-korea-visa-for-italy-citizens#:~:text=South%20Korea%20tourist%20visa%20requirements,intended%20stay%20in%20South%20Korea

@user8469759 you should be all good to go since your passport will still be valid for over 6 months past your trip dates in June. They just want at least that buffer period.
